# Symfony 4 and Doctrine - Why is Doctirne generating multiple declarations of an `$__EXTRA_LINE` variable?

Tags: doctrine, command-line-interface, many-to-one, symfony4

I'm generating a `ManyToOne` association on entities that already exist using the Doctrine CLI.

The generated code is dropping in multiple declarations of a variable `$__EXTRA_LINE` which is not even being called from the class with `$this->`.

This is obviously causing an error when calling `php bin/console make:migration` or running the script due to multiple declarations, and also errors due to undefined variables in the functions (not using `$this->` on in the function body).

Generated code is as follows:

```
private $__EXTRA__LINE; // 1
/**
* @return Collection|JobInvoice[]
*/
public function getJobInvoices(): Collection
{
    return $this->job_invoices;
}
private $__EXTRA__LINE; // 2
public function addJobInvoice(JobInvoice $jobInvoice): self
{
    if (!$this->job_invoices->contains($jobInvoice)) {
        $this->job_invoices[] = $jobInvoice;
        $jobInvoice->setInvoice($this);
    }
    $__EXTRA__LINE; // no '$this->'
    return $this;
}
private $__EXTRA__LINE; // 3
public function removeJobInvoice(JobInvoice $jobInvoice): self
{
    if ($this->job_invoices->contains($jobInvoice)) {
        $this->job_invoices->removeElement($jobInvoice);

        // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
        if ($jobInvoice->getInvoice() === $this) {
         $jobInvoice->setInvoice(null);
        }
    }
    $__EXTRA__LINE; // no '$this->'
    return $this;
}
```

What could be cause this error or is not an error and is it happening for a reason that is important for this `ManyToOne` to work?

Comment: I'm heavily leaning towards this just being an output error. The var is showing where a line break should be. Great is someone could confirm though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the vendor folder in the project:

```
    // this fake property is a placeholder for a linebreak
    $newCode = str_replace('    private $__EXTRA__LINE;', '', $newCode);

    /vendor/symfony/maker-bundle/src/Util/ClassSourceManipulator.php line 611
```

maybe it helps you

Comment: So something is bugging out then. Thanks for that. Any ideas why it's not replacing it with a line break?

Comment: While creating a file, different replace line may be in effect, so they may have done something like this

Comment: At least I know it is safe to delete now. Thanks @Deniz